# Reading a slack topic programmatically

Tags: jenkins, groovy, slack, slack-api

I am attempting to read a slack topic. At the moment when looking at the slack API methods, there is no mentioning of this.

My goal is that with the conversations.SetTopic method I am successfully able to add a topic onto the slack channel. However, I would like to find a way to read that topic programmatically so that my Jenkins automation script could adjust to it.

Is there a way where one could read the topic on a slack channel programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this, It wasn't clear at first as I kept looking for something similar to conversations.SetTopic.

Instead I found out that conversations.list does what I was thinking about which is to read the conversation topic and send it back to me.